# Function satisfying $f(2x^2-1)=(x^3+x)f(x)$

Tags: limits, trigonometry

If  $f : [-1,1]\rightarrow R$ be a continuous function satisfying $f(2x^2-1)=(x^3+x)f(x)$, then find the value of  $\lim\limits_{x \to 0}\dfrac{f(\cos x)}{\sin x}$

My approach is as follow, as the domain is $[-1,1]$, we check the value at $x=-1$, then $f(1)=-2f(-1)$, at $x=1$, then $f(1)=2f(1)$, then $f(1)=0$, hence $f(-1)=0$, putting $x=0$ we get $f(0)=0$.

Now  on differentiating we get $4xf'(2x^2-1)=(3x^2+1)f(x)+(x^3+x)f'(x)$ after this I am not able to solve as it is getting complicated

Comment: Define $g(t) = f(\cos(t))$ and take $x = \cos(t)$ in the functional equation and use trig identities to simplify.

Comment: How do you know $f(x)$ is differentiable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming $f$ is differentiable and plugging in $x=1$ in the differential equation yields $$4f’(1) =2f’(1) \implies f’(1)=0$$ Now, note the limit is of form $\frac 00$, so applying L’Hôpital’s rule we get$$\lim_{x\to 0} \frac{f(\cos x)}{\sin x} =\lim_{x\to 0} \frac{f’(\cos x)\cdot (-\sin x) }{\cos x} = \frac{(\to 0) \cdot (\to 0)}{1} =0$$

Comment: How do you know $f(x)$ is differentiable?

Comment: @QC_QAOA Good point.